# adding subview in a single uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Im facing a problem with adding a UIImageView to a single UITableViewCell. I add the subview like this in the cellForIndexPath delegate method which is ONLY added to the cell if the self.mediaTypeArray contains the string: "Image" at the index: indexPath.row

```
let cell = self.timelineTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier( NSStringFromClass(ClassicCaseCell), forIndexPath: indexPath) as? ClassicCaseCell

if self.mediaTypeArray[indexPath.row] == "Image" {

    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.frame.size = (cell?.evidenceView.frame.size)!
    imageView.frame.origin = CGPointZero
    imageView.image = img

    cell?.evidenceView.addSubview(imageView)
}
```

Which it works great however, I find that every other two cells contains that same imageView even when self.mediaTypeArray[indexPath.row] is NOT equal to "Image" and I don't understand why. I think it may have something to do with reusable tableviewcells but I still don't see why it would do this. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm getting the feeling that this is because of cells being re-used.

A way you can work around this is to override your `ClassicCaseCell`'s `prepareForReuse` method to remove any image view from its `evidenceView`.

I would however recommend that you don't add the image view in this fashion (through the delegate's `cellForIndexPath` method). Instead, your `ClassicCaseCell` should hold the image view as an instance variable which you can then set in `cellForIndexPath`. This way, there is only at most one. You can also make sure to set the image view to be nil in `prepareForReuse`, making sure that it won't appear in the cell if it is not set.

Comment: Thank you! I think ill go with your second option and just assign the image to nil when it is initialised

Answer (score 2):

First, don't use `tag` property as recommended elsewhere. That was a technique used a long time ago, but Apple discourages that practice now. Second, I'd suggest you simplify your life and simply don't programmatically add image views in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. If you programmatically add image views, cell reuse introduces a clumsy process of determining whether (a) you need an image view; (b) whether there is an existing image view; and (c) possibly adding/removing image view and/or getting reference to existing one.

One very simple solution is to just have two cell prototypes, one with an image view and another without. Then, based upon the media type, dequeue a cell with the appropriate storyboard identifier and use it.

The other alternative is to have the image view in the cell regardless, and hide/show it as appropriate. The challenge then becomes how to best manage two sets of the constraints, one for when the image view is visible and one when it's not. You can do this with judicious choice of constraint priorities, activating/deactivating the appropriate constraints in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, etc. It can be done, but this is more cumbersome than the above approach, whereby you just employ two cell prototypes.

Comment: but what if I dont know, how many UIImageViews i require, consider a situation, were imageViews to added are dynamic and depends on the array items. Suppose I need to add UILabel to cells based on the array items, so first cell might contain 1 item, second might contain 2 labels and so on

Comment: you can see my SO question here, where I am facing this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39683959/dynamically-add-subviews-to-uitableviewcell

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add the UIImageView once so if the cell is re-used again, it (might) already be there. Your problem is to detect if you've already added it or not. Here are a couple suggestions:

1) ALWAYS create it (and just don't set the image, or hide it)

2) assign it a unique tag and look for the tag when you need to set it... no tag, then create it

Answer (score 0):

Override prepareForReuse delegation in your tableview cell and remove imageview from there