# Dynamically add subViews to UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uistackview

I need to add UILabels to UITableViewCell, but its dynamic, first cell can have 1 label, second can have 4 and I dont know before hand. So I tried this

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell: ReviewTableViewCell = reviewTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Review", for: indexPath) as! ReviewTableViewCell

        var reviewObj:Review!

        reviewObj = reviewArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]


        let viewsAdded = commentViewsAddedDict[indexPath.row]

        if(viewsAdded == nil)
        {
            for comment in reviewObj.commentArray
            {
                let label1 = UILabel()
                label1.text = “text1”
                label1.textColor =  UIColor(hexString: "#333333")

                let label2 = UILabel()
                label2.text =  “text2”
                label2.numberOfLines = 0
                label2.sizeToFit()
                label2.textColor =  UIColor(hexString: "#666666")

                let label3 = UILabel()
                label3.text = "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
                label3.textColor =  UIColor(hexString: "#eeeeee")


                cell.stackView1.addArrangedSubview(label1)
                cell.stackView1.addArrangedSubview(label2)
                cell.stackView1.addArrangedSubview(label3)
            }

             commentViewsAddedDict[indexPath.row] = true
        }

        return cell
    }
```

But what happens, the previously added views are not removed and it again tries to add new views.

So I want to know, what is the efficient way to do this.
Secondly, where I am going wrong.

Regards
Ranjit

Answer (score 0):

You are using `commentViewsAddedDict` to figure out whether rows have been added or not. But whether these labels were added or not is not a function of the row in the table, but rather of the cell, which is reused.

So, I'd would advise:

- eliminate this `commentViewsAddedDict` logic; and
- move the logic regarding how many labels have been added to `ReviewTableViewCell`.

So, you might end up with:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = reviewTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Review", for: indexPath) as! ReviewTableViewCell

    var reviewObject = reviewArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

    cell.updateLabels(for: reviewObject)

    return cell
}
```

And in `ReviewTableViewCell`:

```
func updateLabels(for reviewObject: ReviewObjectType) {
    // add label if needed

    // update label `text` if needed

    // remove any labels that need to be removed
}
```

It's a little hard to be specific on the logic in `updateLabels` as the provided code snippet in the question is unclear, but the basic idea is that the `ReviewTableViewCell` should keep track of whether its labels have been added or not, and on the basis of the `reviewObject`, decide whether it needs to add a label, update an existing label, or remove any labels not needed for this particular `reviewObject`. But all of this "label state" logic is a function of the cell (which can be reused), not of which row in the table to which the cell corresponds.